# Given a Postion-time curve/function, how do I find the time spent per unit position?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, differentiation, calculus

I have recordings of the position time curve for a given 1D actuator.
I'm trying to find out the time spent per unit length.

To get this relationship, I tried to take an example of a linear function:

$$
p = 5t \;\;\; m \\
v = p' = 5 \;\; m/s \\
1/p' = 1/v = 1/5 \; s/m 
$$

I think this works for linear equations.
Would this work for higher order equations also? If not, what is the right method?

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense, I think it would work well for other types of equations. Since reverse of speed is what you need and to find the reverse of speed you need to find change in time per infinestimal length intervals ($dt/dp$). $p=5t \Rightarrow p/5=t, dt/dp=1/5 s/m$

Comment: I see. 
So basic formula would be: 
Time spent/unit length = $$ 1/p' $$

Comment: I checked this again. This system breaks down when p'->0. 
For example, if p is a 5sin(t)+5, then my p' =5cos(t), therefore time spent per unit length would be infinite at the maximas/minimas.

Comment: Yes. The time spent "at" a point where the momentum is zero blows up. Luckily, what you really have is a *continuous distribution*. In other words, you can use what you have to compute how long it spends in some small *region* in space, in which case you have to integrate your expression in the right way. The result will be non-infinite even if the interval contains a point where the momentum goes to zero.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an equation? I need to convert this to code, so need to get it in some mathematical terms.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4058402/) answer your question?

Comment: Hi BikerDude. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Got it QMechanic, revering to HW problem.

Comment: @BikerDude , [It works for single variable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4058402/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I misunderstood your question, because you use a time dependent $\Delta X(t)$, while my was by definition constant. Nevertheless, I reckon that your main concern is the fact that you are interested in an oscillation motion $x(t) = x_0 \sin(\omega t)$. If this is the case, here my second try ...

#### Second try:

The velocity is given by $v(t)=x_0/\omega \cdot \cos(\omega t) = v_0 \cdot \cos(\omega t)$. The traveled distance $s(t)$ of the oscillator is given by the integral of the velocity w.r.t. time. However, we have to take the absolute value of the velocity, $s(t) = \int_0^t |v(\tau)| d\tau$. To calculate this value analytically, we need to split-up the integral into parts, so that none contains  a zero-point. However, if we perform the integral numerically, this is not an issue.

The following graph displays the position $x(t)$ and the travelled distance $s(t)$

[image]

We see that both start together, but the travelled distance keeps on increasing.

Now, if you wish to find the time for the oscillator to travelled distance a fixed distance, you are calculating $\Delta_s = s(t_0 + \Delta_t) - s(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + \Delta_t} |v(\tau)| d\tau$. Mathematically, this is equivalent of solving the integral as before. Numerically, we use the "root function"
$r(\Delta_t, t_0) = s(t_0 + \Delta_t) - s(t_0) - \Delta_s$.

Using the constant $\Delta_s=0.1$ and the above function, we obtain the time graph

[image]

#### First try:

I probably misunderstood your question. However, you might use my answer to change your question.

Let's denote the position at time $t$ by $x(t)$. Then the velocity at time $t$ is given by $v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$. From what I understood you are interested in the relationship: time $\Delta T$ it takes to change $x$ by a fixed amount $\Delta X$. If this is what you are looking for the answer is
$$
\Delta T(t) = \frac{\Delta X}{v(t)}
$$

That this relationship works can be checked by using any function -- as long as the velocity does not become zero. E.g. here is the plot for the cubic function $x(t) = 0.05 \cdot t^3$

[image]

We see that the time for passing the distance $\Delta X=1$ decreases with increasing time.  This makes sense, because the velocity increases with time.

If instead we use the function $x(t) = 0.4\cdot t + 0.2\cdot \sin(t)$ we get a more interesting plot.

[image]

The linear term generates an "offset" $1/0.4 s = 2.5s$, and the sinus the "wobble". Due to the inverse the wobbling is not symmetric. Thus, again, the above stated relationship makes sense.

Comment: I'm looking for:
$$
\frac{Delta T(t)}{Delta X(t)}
$$

How would you suggest getting this for non-everincreasing curves? Usually speed profiles for real life objects start and end at the same vertical point.

Comment: Don't know if this what you are looking for.

Comment: I think this might be it! 
I was specifically looking for functions which represent real life: Oscillations, increasingSigmoid->constant->decreasingSigmoid etc. 
This seems like it would work for my purposes. I'll try to implement on non-sine functions to validate as well, thanks!

Comment: for your Needed time vs Time T graph, how did you come up with a dt value? What did you exactly plot?

Comment: Sorry, my nomenclature was bad, $dt$ was not (!) infinitesimal. This is why I edited my answer and use $\Delta_t$ instead. What I did is numerically solving the integral for the upper limit. This must be done for an arbitrary, but fixed value $\Delta_s$. I used $\Delta_s=0.1$. In the resulting plot you can see that my chosen starting point of this numerical routine is biased: The solution is not symmetric. I have not checked, if an analytic solution exists, because many programming languages have rather accurate root finding methods.